# Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration'

Tags: spring, reactjs, animation, gatsby

I have a project with Gatsby where I use React Spring.  I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Index property setter is not supported.`

In some of my research I have found that browser updates have been causing this type of error in other scenarios, but I haven't found any that deal with React Spring.

I have tried upgrading all related dependancies to the latest versions.

I have narrowed it down to a part of my code that uses React Spring:

```
const trail = useTrail(2, {
    opacity: sideNav ? 1 : 0,
    x: sideNav ? 0 : 180,
    height: sideNav ? 180 : 0,
    from: { opacity: 0, x: 20, height: 0 },
  });


<NavItem style={trail}>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</NavItem>
```

If I take out style={trail} I no longer get the error so I'm thinking it has something to do with React Spring's useTrail.

I expect it to work as it did a few days ago, where I don't get an error and my animation works as expected.  I actually have not touched the code in a few weeks, and the site was loading correctly just a few days ago.  Now it suddenly breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useTrail` [documentation](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-trail) says:

> The return value is an array containing animated props.

Hence you can't directly apply `trail` to the `style` of one item. It should be something like:

```
{trail.map(style => (
  <NavItem
    style={style}
  >
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </NavItem>
))}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Since it returns an array, and new browser updates have made it so that inline styles can't contain an array, it now throws an error.  I've made the suggested changes and all seems to be working again.  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help :)